# Install Rails 5 without breaking Rails 4.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app on Rails 4.2 which is working fine.

Now I want to install Rails 5 to follow a tutorial which uses Rails 5 and Angular 2. I want to do this without breaking my old app on 4.2, which I cannot afford to mess with.

What is the best way to install Rails 5 and use it only on the new project, without causing any problems to other apps on older versions?

Answer (score 1):

In the old project, set your rails version to 4.2.4 (or your current subversion):

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.4'
```

In the new project, set it to 5.

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0'
```

Comment: I have not installed Rails 5 yet. When I do, isn't the default rails version going to change to 5?

After the default changes to 5, when I open the current rails app (4.2) will it cause conflicts - say by overwriting the rails gem with the new version, and thus creating a set of other gemfile dependencies and breakages?

This is what I have on my gemfile for the current app.
gem 'rails', '4.2'

Comment: 5.1 got released last week. But give it a few weeks for all the gems to catch up.